# Bidirectional communication between c++ dll and C# dll

Tags: c#, c++, com, clr

I am trying to establish a **bidirectional** communication between my **C++ dll** and **C# dll**. C++ dll is an addin that is loaded by a 3rd party application. And all my UI is in c# which is triggered by functions in c++ dll. I want to get a callback in my c++ dll when action is taken on the C# form (e.g. button click).

I have tried making C# dll a COM component but was unable to get a callback to native/unmanaged c++. So I also tried making a CLR bridge as suggested in many answers. But there, I get a call back to CLR dll, not to native C++ dll.

Is this possible? Any help is highly appreciated. I can provide more specific details if required.

Comment: You just want to have your main function in your C# project and then every time e.g. a button clicked, some event happen and a function runs on your C++ project then (of course) the result shows on C# UI. and your C++ project isn't a clr one. Am I right?

Comment: The C++ project is not clr as you guessed it correctly. But I can't have the main function in C#. The C# dll is just a part of the project. It contains only dumb UI which is controlled by C++ dll. The decision of launching different C# forms and taking action on clicks is with C++. I hope it's clear.

Comment: So you have a main C# project, a non CLR C++ project and some C# forms. actions (clicks) are coming from Forms and the main C# project call some functions from C++ dll, get the result and again send to forms or decide to do something else.

Comment: You can say that C# project is a library that has some api classes e.g. there's a DisplayForm, which has public function ShowForm(). C++ dll can create instance of the class if it's COM and call ShowForm(); So main project is C++ addin dll which is controlling the C# dll.